# Is it possible to keep puff pastry dough in the fridge for future use?

Tags: dough, puff-pastry

I made puff pastry but there's extra dough in my kitchen that I don't want to make more Torte Milanese for which I needed puff pastry. The extra dough doesn't contain butter and is not the required dough yet. Where and how to keep it for future use?

Comment: We don't do recipe requests, but your question about keeping it in the fridge is acceptable :)

Comment: @Yamikuronue: As you've probably noticed, I said  "name" it and didn't ask for a recipe.

Comment: So what you've got is just flour, salt and water, right?

Comment: Right @Jolenealaska

Comment: @gigili we also don't accept "suggest a dish which I can make with ingredient X" type of question, so Yamikuronue was correct in removing that part.

Comment: I would finish the butter folding, then freeze it.

Answer (score 1):

The dough will keep 2-3 days only in the fridge. Freeze and defrost when you need it and it will keep for a month or more. Just wrap it well to prevent off flavors and freezer burn.